# Large table querying

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a database table that accepts more than 2,000,000 records each month. I have created it as a partitioned table. All searchable fields are indexed. But when applying a paging select on the table by the `with` keyword it takes long time to get the result.

Is there any other solution to tune this table's performance?

Answer (score 1):

There is a more efficient way of paging described [here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/070628.htm).